# Helpful flags should be shown in the same layout as votes cast

Tags: feature-request, design, flag-history

It would be nice if "helpful flags" will be shown in the same layout as "votes cast" and "post edited". Actually if I look at the votes cast I can see the header and navigate to other pages.[image]

If I look at "helpful flags" the top bar is gone and I have to navigate back and then I can navigate to another page:

Think it is better usability if in this view the header will be viewed, so that we can navigate as in all other parts of the user statistics in stackoverflow.

[image]

Comment: Agreed. I find it awkward at present to check on my flags. Other activity is so much more readily visible.

Comment: Plus people will actually discover that 1) the system and moderators do keep count of their flags and 2) moderators do respond to their flags.